# VBA - CountIf cell range displayed value is equal to desired value

Tags: vba, excel, countif

I am having an issue running my code through, because the `Range.Value` is different than the `Range.NumberFormat`.  For example, my value is a date and time and I would like to test for the day of the week. I was able to get the number format to be Sun-Sat, however, I am unsure how to test for it with `CountIf`.

```
Dim rep         as Worksheet
Dim day         As Range
Dim time        As Range
Dim wf          As WorksheetFunction
Set rep = Worksheets("Report")
Set day = rep.Range("H1", rep.Range("H1").End(xlDown))
Set time = rep.Range("I1", rep.Range("I1").End(xlDown))
Set wf = WorksheetFunction

With rep
    .Columns("H").NumberFormat = "dddd"
    .Columns("I").NumberFormat = "AM/PM"

    .Range("K1") = "Monday"
    .Range("K2") = "Tuesday"
    .Range("K3") = "Wednesday"
    .Range("K4") = "Thursday"
    .Range("K5") = "Friday"
    .Range("K6") = "Saturday"
    .Range("K7") = "Sunday"

    .Range("M1") = "AM"
    .Range("M2") = "PM"

        .Range("L1") = wf.CountIf(day, "Monday")
        .Range("L2") = wf.CountIf(day, "Tuesday")
        .Range("L3") = wf.CountIf(day, "Wednesday")
        .Range("L4") = wf.CountIf(day, "Thursday")
        .Range("L5") = wf.CountIf(day, "Friday")
        .Range("L6") = wf.CountIf(day, "Saturday")
        .Range("L7") = wf.CountIf(day, "Sunday")

    .Range("N1") = wf.CountIf(time, "AM")
    .Range("N2") = wf.CountIf(time, "PM")
End With
```

This is what I have so far, but it only outputs 0 for the solution to the `countif`.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: your countif should not be in a loop as it wants a multi-cell range and not one cell.  `wf.CountIf(day,...)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Attempted that as well, but it also was not working, I have fixed that above.

Comment: also `.Columns("H").NumberFormat = "dddd"` does not change the data to the day it is a mask and the underlying value is still date.  so it will never = "Monday" as it is a number like `42563` that is formatted like 'dddd'  Add the following after the numberformat: `.Columns("H:I").Value = .Columns("H:I").Text`

Comment: If you want to check the day of the week of a date, why not just use the VBA `Weekday` function?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Can You further explain what you mean?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I am unsure if that method would work, because this is an example of the cell value `"12/26/2016  7:29:27 AM"`

Comment: I'm guessing you want to count how many of each Weekday are in your range of dates in column H.  Just loop through the range, test each entry with the Weekday function, and you will have your results.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?  It should work independent of the format of the cell.  See the example I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way to do the counts.
Note I did most of the "work" in VBA arrays as this is much faster than repeatedly accessing the worksheet:

**EDIT**: To include counting the number of entries in column H with AM or PM times

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
    Dim rep As Worksheet
    Dim rDts As Range
    Dim vDts As Variant
    Dim vCnts As Variant 'for the weekday count
    Dim vAP As Variant   'for the AM PM count
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

Set rep = Worksheets("sheet1")
'read dates into array -- faster processing
With rep
    vDts = .Range(.Cells(1, 8), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
End With

'Results array
ReDim vCnts(1 To 7, 1 To 2)
    vCnts(1, 1) = "Sunday"
    vCnts(2, 1) = "Monday"
    vCnts(3, 1) = "Tuesday"
    vCnts(4, 1) = "Wednesday"
    vCnts(5, 1) = "Thursday"
    vCnts(6, 1) = "Friday"
    vCnts(7, 1) = "Saturday"

ReDim vAP(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
    vAP(1, 1) = "AM"
    vAP(2, 1) = "PM"
'Do the counts
    For I = 1 To UBound(vDts, 1)
        J = Weekday(vDts(I, 1))
        vCnts(J, 2) = vCnts(J, 2) + 1

        'Check for AM or PM
        If Hour(vDts(I, 1)) < 12 Then
            vAP(1, 2) = vAP(1, 2) + 1
        Else
            vAP(2, 2) = vAP(2, 2) + 1
        End If

    Next I

'output the results
rep.Range("K1:L7").Value = vCnts
rep.Range("M1:N2").Value = vAP

End Sub
```

Comment: What about for `"AM"/"PM"`

Comment: Use the VBA `Hour` function on the same date/time entry and test if it is less than 12 (=AM). Otherwise it will be PM

Comment: Sorry for all of the questions, but I have never used these methods which you included, but can I just for a `For and If` statement, or should I do something like what you did?

Comment: Please ask again if there is anything about the code you do not understand.