# VBA - Countifs time and date by building using variants

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, variant

I received help in solving a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601437/vba-countif-cell-range-displayed-value-is-equal-to-desired-value).  I would like to solve this problem similarly.

So the situation is similar to a `Countifs` function, in that I would like it to count if a range equals a certain building, as well as if the date and time that is offset equals a certain date.  For example, if the cell in `"C1" = "Irving Building"` And if the value in `"K1" = "Monday"` Then I would like it to display in `"S1"`.  More specifically if `"C1" = "Irving Building"` then I want it to count into whatever day and time that corresponds with it, in `Column K`.

```
Private Sub TimeAndDate()

Dim n           As Double
Dim rep         As Worksheet
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim LastRow     As Double

Set rep = Worksheets("Report")

rep.Columns("K:L").ClearContents

For n = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    Set ws = Worksheets(n)

    If IsNumeric(ws.Name) Then
        LastRow = rep.Range("K1", rep.Range("K1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        LastRow = LastRow + 1

        If rep.Range("K1") = "" Then
            ws.Range("C2", ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy _
            Destination:=rep.Range("K1")
            ws.Range("C2", ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy _
            Destination:=rep.Range("L1")
        Else:
            ws.Range("C2", ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy _
            Destination:=rep.Range("K" & LastRow)
            ws.Range("C2", ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Copy _
            Destination:=rep.Range("L" & LastRow)
        End If

    End If

Next n

    Dim rDts As Range
    Dim vDts As Variant
    Dim vCnts As Variant
    Dim vAP As Variant    'for the AM PM count
    Dim vDbld As Variant  'for the date by building
    Dim vTbld As Variant  'for thee time by building
    Dim i As Long, J As Long

'read dates into array -- faster processing
With rep
    vDts = .Range(.Cells(1, 11), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp))
End With

'Results array
ReDim vCnts(1 To 7, 1 To 2)
    vCnts(1, 1) = "Sunday"
    vCnts(2, 1) = "Monday"
    vCnts(3, 1) = "Tuesday"
    vCnts(4, 1) = "Wednesday"
    vCnts(5, 1) = "Thursday"
    vCnts(6, 1) = "Friday"
    vCnts(7, 1) = "Saturday"

ReDim vAP(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
    vAP(1, 1) = "AM"
    vAP(2, 1) = "PM"

ReDim vDbld(1 To 13, 1 To 2)
    vDbld(1, 1) = "Irving Building"
    vDbld(2, 1) = "Memorial Building"
    vDbld(3, 1) = "West Tower"
    vDbld(4, 1) = "Witting Surgical Center"
    vDbld(5, 1) = "Madison Irving Surgical Center"
    vDbld(6, 1) = "Marley Education Center"
    vDbld(7, 1) = "410 South Crouse"
    vDbld(8, 1) = "Physicians Office Building"
    vDbld(9, 1) = "Crouse Business Center"
    vDbld(10, 1) = "Commonwealth Place"
    vDbld(11, 1) = "Irving - Memorial Connector"
    vDbld(12, 1) = "Crouse Garage"
    vDbld(13, 1) = "CNY Medical Center"

'Do the counts
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDts, 1)

        J = Weekday(vDts(i, 1))
        vCnts(J, 2) = vCnts(J, 2) + 1

        If Hour(vDts(i, 1)) < 12 Then
            vAP(1, 2) = vAP(1, 2) + 1
        Else
            vAP(2, 2) = vAP(2, 2) + 1
        End If


    Next i

'output the results
rep.Range("E1:E14").Copy rep.Range("Q1")
rep.Range("N2:N8").Copy
rep.Range("R1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
False, True
rep.Range("N11:N12").Copy
rep.Range("Y1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, _
False, True

rep.Range("N1") = "DATE"
rep.Range("O1") = "COUNT"
rep.Range("N10") = "TIME"
rep.Range("O10") = "COUNT"
rep.Range("N2:O8").Value = vCnts
rep.Range("N11:O12").Value = vAP
```

The part that I am needing help on is this part here.  These are the variants that I'd like to use, but like I said, earlier, I am unsue as to how to do this without running a ton of `countifs` statements.

```
    Dim vDbld As Variant  'for the date by building
ReDim vDbld(1 To 13, 1 To 2)
    vDbld(1, 1) = "Irving Building"
    vDbld(2, 1) = "Memorial Building"
    vDbld(3, 1) = "West Tower"
    vDbld(4, 1) = "Witting Surgical Center"
    vDbld(5, 1) = "Madison Irving Surgical Center"
    vDbld(6, 1) = "Marley Education Center"
    vDbld(7, 1) = "410 South Crouse"
    vDbld(8, 1) = "Physicians Office Building"
    vDbld(9, 1) = "Crouse Business Center"
    vDbld(10, 1) = "Commonwealth Place"
    vDbld(11, 1) = "Irving - Memorial Connector"
    vDbld(12, 1) = "Crouse Garage"
    vDbld(13, 1) = "CNY Medical Center"
```

I apologize if this is confusing, I am not completely sure how to word it, thanks in advance.

This is an example of what I'd like it to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you simply can is to check with `Application.Match` if the string is in the array and it will give back the index, because this function can only handle one dimensional arrays, there is another function that will give back one dimension of the array. After that you can check the offset and do something with it like this:

```
Dim mindex as Variant
mindex = Application.Match(rDts(i, 3), Only1D(vDbld, 1), 0)
If Not IsError(mindex) Then
   'do stuff i.e
   vDbld(mindex, 2) = vDbld(mindex, 2) + 1
End If

Function Only1D(arr As Variant, d As Long)
Dim size As Long: size = UBound(arr, d)
Dim arr2 As Variant
ReDim arr2(1 To size)
For i = 1 To size
    arr2(i) = arr(i, d)
Next
Only1D = arr2
End Function
```

Comment: I have added a photo of what I'd like it to look similar too.  With your code, wouldn't that count it for every one? I am not understanding the logic?

Comment: Your question is not precise. with the code i provided u can get the row/index of the array and then do the stuff with the date you want to do.

Comment: You would know have to check for the date and then handle it the way you want it. Also why do you even use 2 dimensional arrays?